# Unable to access quill instance within a module function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures, quill

I have:

```
    const formats = ['header', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'list', 'prediction', 'accepted', 'mention'];
    const modules = {
        mention: {
            allowedChars: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/,
            mentionDenotationChars: ['@'],
            showDenotationChar: false,
            spaceAfterInsert: false,
            onSelect: (item, insertItem) => {
                clearDocumentState(0)
                const cursorPos = quill.getSelection()
                console.log({ cursorPos })
                insertItem(item)
            },
            source: () => { }
        },
        toolbar: [
            ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
            [{ list: 'ordered' }, { list: 'bullet' }],
            [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
            ['clean']
        ]
    };

    const { quill, quillRef, Quill } = useQuill({
        formats,
        modules,
        placeholder: 'Start writing something amazing...'
    });
```

I'm using https://github.com/afry/quill-mention and https://github.com/gtgalone/react-quilljs if it matters.

When I try to access the `quill` instance in the `onSelect` function, I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelection' of undefined
```

I assume somehow the function is cached and `quill` isn't defined yet. Any way to get that instance?

Comment: Not sure what quill is, but have you try to put useQuill above modules declaration?

Comment: I can't because I need `modules` when defining `quill`

Comment: and there is no way to register your mention module on a useEffect with a dependency of quill, so if it exist, then you register the "mentions" module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `onSelect` callback in `useEffect` block when quill has value. Use [getModule](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#getmodule) to get the `mention` module and set the corresponding `option`:

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    if (quill) {
      quill.getModule('mention').options.onSelect = ((item, insertItem) => {
        clearDocumentState(0);
        const cursorPos = quill.getSelection();
        console.log({ cursorPos });
        insertItem(item);
      });
    }
  }, [quill]);
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-w3rhh6?file=src%2FApp.js)